# External HDD unable to be mounted / shows empty partition after putting in a new case

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I have a 1TB external hard drive for storing my data. Unfortunately the USB connector became loose, so that the HDD didn't work anymore. So I just bought a new 2.5" case and put my HDD in the new case.

My computer recognizes the HDD and I can see the size of the two partitions via GParted. Also it is recognized by dmesg:

```
dmesg | tail -n 20
```

Gives me:

```
[12628.586417] usb 4-6: new high-speed USB device number 22 using ehci-pci
[12628.720908] usb 4-6: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa
[12628.720914] usb 4-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[12628.720917] usb 4-6: Product: AS2115
[12628.720919] usb 4-6: Manufacturer: ASMedia
[12628.720921] usb 4-6: SerialNumber: 201403060029
[12628.721467] usb-storage 4-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[12628.721872] usb-storage 4-6:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 55aa: 400000
[12628.722040] scsi29 : usb-storage 4-6:1.0
[12629.720322] scsi 29:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ASMedia  AS2115           0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[12629.721100] sd 29:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
[12629.725921] sd 29:0:0:0: [sde] Spinning up disk...
[12630.728215] .....ready
[12634.765128] sd 29:0:0:0: [sde] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[12634.765140] sd 29:0:0:0: [sde] 4096-byte physical blocks
[12634.766251] sd 29:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
[12634.766264] sd 29:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[12634.767391] sd 29:0:0:0: [sde] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[12634.803213]  sde: sde1
[12634.807784] sd 29:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
```

But I'm not able to mount any of the partitions. There should be two NTFS partitions, but only one of them is recognized (but not as a valid NTFS).
The other partitions is recognized as empty space (but I know that there is my data on it).

I don't want to reformat my HDD, because all of my backups are on there.

Any suggestions what to try?

**EDIT**

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sde
```

Gives me:

```
Disk /dev/sde: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x31068305
Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sde1         256 244008447 244008192 116,4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

So, there is only one partition instead of two, and the one partition is not able to be mounted.

Comment: What said you `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sde`?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: Check the original model of the external. Some external HDDs have build-in hardware encryption, should that be the case the data won't be readable without the enclosure.

Comment: how should i check that? my external hdd has a separate partition with some windows-encryption tool to install, so that the other partition can optionally be encrypted. but i never used that feature. would it make sense to give such a tool AND use hardware encryption?